# JWT Token verification both on client-side and server-side in MERN webapp

Tags: express, jwt, mern

I'm in a huge fight few months with JWT tokens which I use in my MERN app and I can't resolve why my verifyToken middleware seems not working when I try to access in my client-side only for authorized users pages. Thanks to Redux.js without a token you can't access protected pages but it's just client-side verification and I know that both server and client side verifications would be great.

CORS and cookie-parser packages are set up, token cookie being created right after user is logging in. I'm sure that there isn't any problem with imports and other silly mistakes. I also discovered that in Insomnia all works fine. The issue is just in the browser. Any clues?

**verifyToken.js**

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.cookies.token;
  if (!token) return res.status(401).send("Unauthorized");

  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY);
    req.user = decoded.user;
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(498).send("Invalid token");
  }
};

export default verifyToken;
```

**index.js** fragment

```
const app = express();

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors({ origin: "http://localhost:3000", credentials: true }));

app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);
app.use("/p/*", protectedRoute); // is it correct?
```

**protectedRoute.js**

```
import express from "express";
import protectedPages from "../controllers/protectedController.js";
import verifyToken from "../middlewares/verifyToken.js";

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", verifyToken, protectedPages);

export default router;
```

**protectedController.js**

```
const protectedPages = (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send("Token verified");
};

export default protectedPages;
```